# Requirements for App Store Review Video?

Tags: ios-appstore

**Background:**

When submitting an (iOS) application for review which has functionality depending on a specific hardware, Apple asks for a Video, demonstrating the feature(s).

> If we’re not able to access part of your app because it’s geo-locked or otherwise restricted, provide a link to a video of the functionality

([source](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/))

**The Question:**

**Are there any requirements or restrictions on this video?**

(Examples: Can it be edited or should it be continuous? Can it be uploaded to a video sharing site or otherwise where should it be hosted? etc.).

Comment: @Allan This question can't *only* be answered by Apple, anyone can answer this, either through experience, through their previous app submissions, or through finding another source?

Comment: @Allan I agree, everything you've said is true but nothing you've said would suggest that would make it off-topic? There are plenty of questions about what Apple wants and plenty of answers from experience or by quoting a relevant source.

Comment: @grgarside- True...gave it some thought and retracted my vote.

Answer (score 2):

You can host it on a site like Vimeo or YouTube. Set the **video unlisted** and send Apple the private URL.

You can do do **some editing** to clarify upfront what will be shown next. Please **include all necessary steps** to use your app.

Shorten a process in post if it takes very long. Indicate *that* and *by how much* it was shortened.

Good luck with your app!

Comment: Do you have maybe a source where you got these informations from? Or experience with posting an app for review with a video?

Comment: @Steeve this is what I learnt when I worked with another developer in 2016.